# Row Colors Hide Text and Clines in a Table

Tags: tables

I have the following table. As you can see the some part of the text in multi-rows is hidden. Also, the cline between rows 1 and 2 is not displayed.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{As can be seen the text in the multirow part is hidden in half by the color. Also, the cline is not displaying even with zooming in the viewer.}
\begin{tabular}{cccccccccc}
\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{0.85}
\multirow{2}{*}{X} & \multirow{2}{*}{Y} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$(1,1)$} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$(10,10)$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$(100,100)$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$(1000,1000)$} \\
\cline{3-10}
\rowcolor[gray]{0.85}
& & A & Error & B & Error & A & Error & B & Error \\
\hline
0   & & & & & & & & & \\
0.1 & & & & & & & & & \\
0.2 & & & & & & & & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the problem of text half hidden in `multirow` cells, you just have to do insert `\multirow` on the last line with a negative number of rows. Concerning `\cline`s and coloured cells, this is a known problem. The solution usually consists in using `hhline`, which doesn't have this flaw, but I prefer to use the rules of `booktabs`, which can have variable thickness, after I set their vertical padding to 0 to have no white strips.

Also, I loaded `caption` to have a decent vertical spacing between caption and table when the caption is above the table:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow, caption, booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\caption{As can be seen the text in the multirow part is hidden in half by the color. Also, the cline is not displaying even with zooming in the viewer.}
\begin{tabular}{cccccccccc}
\toprule
\rowcolor[gray]{0.85}
\multirow{2}{*}{\cellcolor[gray]{0.85}} & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$(1,1)$} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$(10,10)$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$(100,100)$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$(1000,1000)$} \\
\arrayrulecolor[gray]{0.85}\midrule\noalign{\vspace*{-\cmidrulewidth}}%
\arrayrulecolor{black}\cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6}\cmidrule(lr){7-8}\cmidrule(lr){9-10}
\rowcolor[gray]{0.85}
\multirow{-2}{*}{X} & \multirow{-2}{*}{Y} & A & Error & B & Error & A & Error & B & Error \\
\midrule
0 & & & & & & & & & \\
0.1 & & & & & & & & & \\
0.2 & & & & & & & & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Many thanks for the answer. :) One more thing. Is there any way that I can have the line below the pairs (1,1),(10,10),etc to be discontinuous. That is something like ----, just below the pairs.

Comment: It' possible: you code `\cmidrule(lr){3-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-6}`, &c. Unfortunately, this introduces white lines on the shortened part of the lines. I'll try to see if there's a work-around.

Comment: @H.R. I'ved posted a code  which solves the problem: the trick is to first draw a `\midrule` of the same colour as the background, then draw the (black) `\cmidrule(lr)`s.

Answer (score 1):

With the environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have directly the expected output.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{cc*{4}{wc{5mm}wc{10mm}}}[code-before = \rowcolor[gray]{0.85}{1,2}]
\toprule
\Block{2-1}{X}&\Block{2-1}{Y} &\Block{1-2}{$(1,1)$} && \Block{1-2}{$(10,10)$} && \Block{1-2}{$(100,100)$} && \Block{1-2}{$(1000,1000)$} & \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6}\cmidrule(lr){7-8}\cmidrule(lr){9-10}
& & A & Error & B & Error & A & Error & B & Error \\
\midrule
0 \\
0.1 \\
0.2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]