# The text in column one, row two is hidden after addition of a background color. Not sure how to fix it

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

%size of paper
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }

\title{Trial}
\author{ble}
\date{March 2021}

%tables
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{20pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{adjustbox}



\begin {document} 


\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}
\newcolumntype{a}{>{\columncolor{Gray}}M{1cm}}
\begin{table}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-0.1in}{-1in}
    \begin{tabular}{|a|M{3.5cm}|M{9cm}|}
    \hline
       \rowcolor{lightgray} Type  & Item & Discharge Method \\
       \hline
        \multirow{4}{*}{Paper} & Newspapers & 
                While disposing it should not be wet, one should spread it out evenly or should be tied into a single pile.
                Advertisements coated with vinyl, vinyl, and other dirt should not be mixed \\
             \cline{2-3}
            {} & Brochures, Notebooks, Paper Shopping Bags, Calendar, Wrappers & 
                  Remove the vinyl-coated cover and spring from the notebook. Discharge separately. Plastic wrapping paper is excluded
             \\
             \cline{2-3}
            {} & Paper Cups, Paper Packs & 
                Empty the contents, rinse it with water, squeeze it, dispose in a bag or bundle it together.\\
            \cline{2-3}
            {} & Boxes (Snacks, Package Boxes, Corrugated Boxes, etc.) & Remove the vinyl coating, tape attached to the box and staples, crush or fold for easier transportation \\
            \hline
            \multirow{2}{*}{Cans} & Iron Cans, Aluminum Cans (Drinks and Foods) &  Empty contents, rinse with water and squeeze if possible. \\
            \cline{2-3}
            {} & Other Cans (Butane Gas, Pesticide Containers) & Empty content by drilling a hole, remove plastic cap if present and dispose. Dispose in a bag (vinyl bag is permitted).
            \\
            \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Bottles} &  Beverage Bottles and Other Bottles & Remove the bottle cap, empty the contents, rinse it with water and discharge it separately. 
    Do not put foreign substances such as cigarette butts
* For beer bottles, etc., the empty container and deposit system is used at retail stores, etc. \\
\cline{2-3}
{} & Pesticide Bottles & Rinse it with water and discharge it separately do not mix with beverage bottles. \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Metals}
{} & Scrap Metals (Tools, Steel Wires, Nails, Iron Plates, Electric Wires, etc.) &
Prevent mixing with foreign substances, place in a transparent bag or tie it with a string to dispose. \\

\cline{2-3}
{} & Non-ferrous Metals (Nickel Silvers, Aluminums, Stainless Steels) & Prevent mixing with foreign substances, place in a transparent bag or tie it with a string to dispose.\\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Plastics} & PET bottles, Synthetic resin containers. 

& Remove lid, empty contents, rinse with water and squeeze it to reduce the volume, as much as possible
* Excluding waste oil containers. \\
\cline{2-3}
{} & Household goods & Remove foreign substances, attached trademarks, etc. completely and place in a transparent vinyl or bundle them to dispose them.
Empty the residue of fruits and fish boxes completely and rinse thoroughly with water to dispose. \\
\cline{2-3}
{} & Waste Styrofoam & Excluding disposable cup noodle containers, lunch boxes and waste Styrofoam coated with foreign substances or other materials (PE, PP, etc.) \\
\hline

Textiles & Pure Wool, Mixed Wool, Innerwear, Outwear, etc. &
Except wet clothes, nylon, disposable diapers, quilted blankets, etc. Tie it using a string or dispose in a box or transparent vinyl. \\
\hline 
Batteries & MR, SR & Dispose in a transparent vinyl or box. \\

\hline 

Vinyl & Snack Bags, Ramen Bags, Household Rubber Gloves, Disposable Plastic Bags, etc. & Only plastic bags are collected separately and discharged. If foreign substances such as food are smeared, wash them thoroughly and dispose. \\
\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustwidth}
    \caption{Recyclables}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you please post a *complete* code that we can compile as is?

Comment: Since you use `\multirow` in your table and also mention row color, I guess, your question is realted to the following: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/392673/134144

Comment: Apart from the multirow and color related issue, you might want to adjust the first argument of the `\multirow` command, if you want to vertically center the contents of the first column. Since your table is quite long and most likely too long to fit onto a single page, you might also want to consider switching to `longtable`, which allows mid-table page breaks.

Comment: Personally, I would redesign the table in order to avoid all vertical and most horizontal lines. I'd also try to get rid of the first column in order to reduce the amound of "wasted" white space. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/585139/134144 for example shows such a redesign.

Comment: @Bernard Hello, Thanks I have updated as asked.

Comment: @leandriis Hi, thanks. I did try \multirow wiith the link you sent before i posted the question because it did not work for some reason. I also do not want to break the table into two separate pages hence did not use \long table

Comment: Please update your question to show exactly what you tried. The answer, I linked to in my comment should also work for your table.

Comment: Since you mention not wanting to split the table over multiple pages: Did you notice that your table does in fact not fit onto the page you specified? If you look closely, you can see that its caption overlaps with the page number. You will also get a warning alo g the lines of "Float too large by...pt".

Comment: Remove `\multirow{4}{*}{Paper}` from the line you currently used it in and instead add `\multirow{-8}{*}{Paper}` in the line that contains the text "Boxes (Snacks, Package Boxes,...".

Answer (score 1):

You can do that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` with several avantages.

- In `{NiceTabular}`, you have a command `\Block`to merge cells both vertically and horizontally. Vertically, you specify the number of *logical* rows and not the number of *physical* lines as with `\multirow`.
- You can color rows and columns without the trick of a negative argument for `\multirow`.
- You can draw all the rules with the key `hvlines`.
- You won't see the thin white lines you see in Zarko's answer.

However, there is no `x` column type in `{NiceTabular}` (maybe in a future version). In my example, I have done a computation in order to have a behaviour such in `{tabularx}` (I have taken the values of Zarko's answer).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits=5pt}

\title{Trial}
\author{ble}
\date{March 2021}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}      % thicker arrayrules
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}               % reduced separation between column content from their borders
\begin{NiceTabular}[hvlines]
              {m{4em}
               >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr (\textwidth -4em -6\tabcolsep -4\arrayrulewidth)/10*3}
               >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr (\textwidth -4em -6\tabcolsep -4\arrayrulewidth)/10*7}}
\CodeBefore
    \columncolor{gray!85}{1}
    \rowcolor{lightgray}{1}
\Body
 Type  & Item & Discharge Method \\
\Block{3-1}{Paper}
    & Newspapers 
        & While disposing it should not be wet, one should spread it out evenly or should be tied into a single pile. Advertisements coated with vinyl, vinyl, and other dirt should not be mixed
        \\  
    & Brochures, Notebooks, Paper Shopping Bags, Calendar, Wrappers 
        &   Remove the vinyl-coated cover and spring from the notebook. Discharge separately. Plastic wrapping paper is excluded
        \\  
    & Paper Cups, Paper Packs 
        & Empty the contents, rinse it with water, squeeze it, dispose in a bag or bundle it together.
        \\  
\Block{2-1}{Cans}
    & Boxes (Snacks, Package Boxes, Corrugated Boxes, etc.) 
        & Remove the vinyl coating, tape attached to the box and staples, crush or fold for easier transportation 
        \\  
    & Iron Cans, Aluminum Cans (Drinks and Foods) 
        &  Empty contents, rinse with water and squeeze if possible. 
        \\  
\Block{2-1}{Bottles}
    & Other Cans (Butane Gas, Pesticide Containers) 
        & Empty content by drilling a hole, remove plastic cap if present and dispose. Dispose in a bag (vinyl bag is permitted).
        \\  
    &  Beverage Bottles and Other Bottles 
        & Remove the bottle cap, empty the contents, rinse it with water and discharge it separately. Do not put foreign substances such as cigarette butts 
        * For beer bottles, etc., the empty container and deposit system is used at retail stores, etc. 
        \\  
    & Pesticide Bottles 
        & Rinse it with water and discharge it separately do not mix with beverage bottles. 
        \\  
\Block{2-1}{Metals}
    & Scrap Metals (Tools, Steel Wires, Nails, Iron Plates, Electric Wires, etc.) 
        & Prevent mixing with foreign substances, place in a transparent bag or tie it with a string to dispose. 
        \\  
    & Non-ferrous Metals (Nickel Silvers, Aluminums, Stainless Steels) 
        & Prevent mixing with foreign substances, place in a transparent bag or tie it with a string to dispose.
        \\  
\Block{3-1}{Plastics}
    & PET bottles, Synthetic resin containers.
        & Remove lid, empty contents, rinse with water and squeeze it to reduce the volume, as much as possible
        * Excluding waste oil containers. 
        \\  
    & Household goods 
        & Remove foreign substances, attached trademarks, etc. completely and place in a transparent vinyl or bundle them to dispose them.
        Empty the residue of fruits and fish boxes completely and rinse thoroughly with water to dispose. 
        \\  
    & Waste Styrofoam 
        & Excluding disposable cup noodle containers, lunch boxes and waste Styrofoam coated with foreign substances or other materials (PE, PP, etc.) \\
Textiles 
    & Pure Wool, Mixed Wool, Innerwear, Outwear, etc. 
        & Except wet clothes, nylon, disposable diapers, quilted blankets, etc. Tie it using a string or dispose in a box or transparent vinyl. \\
Batteries 
    & MR, SR 
        & Dispose in a transparent vinyl or box. 
        \\  
Vinyl 
    & Snack Bags, Ramen Bags, Household Rubber Gloves, Disposable Plastic Bags, etc. 
        & Only plastic bags are collected separately and discharged. If foreign substances such as food are smeared, wash them thoroughly and dispose. 
        \\  
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{Recyclables}
\label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should expand or clarify your question.

I compiled your table as

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}

<your MWE>

\end{document}
```

and did not found any missing row. Or was it another background color that you added?

Not related: delete the blank lines you have in the tabular environment.

[image: xx]

Comment: Hey thank but yes it was after the addition of color not prior to that.

Comment: So everything is alright now?

Comment: hm, OP has first column in gray color ant it cover text in `\multirow` cells.

Answer (score 0):

When you have colored (multirow) cells, you need to add text in them after coloring. In your case this mean, that `\multirow` had to be inserted in the last row, which it spanned and have negative number of lines spanned by it in this rows as is done in MWE below.

*Off-topic*:

- please always provide compilable MWE (Minimal Working Example), in your is missed code line `\end{document}`.
- please load each package only ones
- group them according for their purpose fonts, math, tables,...)
- instead stretching array rather insert vertical gaps before and after cells' contents by use of `cellspace` (as is done in MWE below)
- instead `tabular` in my opinion it is better to use `tabularx` and omit use of `adjustidth` macro from `changepage` macro
- for vertical centering contents of cells in `C` colums is renewed type of `X` column cells by `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}`, see MWE below
- instead of old `chngpage`, which is deprecated, is better to use new one with option `strict`, i.e.: it should be loaded as: `\usepackage[strict]{changepage}`
- negative number of spanned lines by `\multirow` is calculated as *<number of lines - size of added vertical gapes and horizontal rules>* where the added vertical size is estimated in number of text  lines. For example, the first `multirow cell spanned 11 text lines with inserted 8 gaps

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            margin=2cm]{geometry}
% fonts
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
% math
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}% amsfonts is loaded by amssymb
%tables
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage[column=O]{cellspace}% better, than {} aren't necessary
    \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
    \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx, threeparttable}
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash
                           \hsize=#1\hsize}X }
    \addparagraphcolumntypes{C}
% miscellaneous
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}  
\usepackage{adjustbox}   


\title{Trial}
\author{ble}
\date{March 2021}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}  % vertical centered X cells contents
    \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}      % thicker arrayrules
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}               % reduced separation between column content from their borders
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\columncolor{gray!85}}p{4em}|
                                    O{C{0.3}}|
                                    O{C{0.7}}|}
    \hline
\rowcolor{lightgray} Type  & Item & Discharge Method \\
    \hline
    & Newspapers 
        & While disposing it should not be wet, one should spread it out evenly or should be tied into a single pile. Advertisements coated with vinyl, vinyl, and other dirt should not be mixed
        \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Brochures, Notebooks, Paper Shopping Bags, Calendar, Wrappers 
        &   Remove the vinyl-coated cover and spring from the notebook. Discharge separately. Plastic wrapping paper is excluded
        \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Paper Cups, Paper Packs 
        & Empty the contents, rinse it with water, squeeze it, dispose in a bag or bundle it together.
        \\  \cline{2-3}
\multirow{-9}{=}{Paper}
    & Boxes (Snacks, Package Boxes, Corrugated Boxes, etc.) 
        & Remove the vinyl coating, tape attached to the box and staples, crush or fold for easier transportation 
        \\  \hline
    & Iron Cans, Aluminum Cans (Drinks and Foods) 
        &  Empty contents, rinse with water and squeeze if possible. 
        \\  \cline{2-3}
\multirow{-3}{=}{Cans}
    & Other Cans (Butane Gas, Pesticide Containers) 
        & Empty content by drilling a hole, remove plastic cap if present and dispose. Dispose in a bag (vinyl bag is permitted).
        \\  \hline
    &  Beverage Bottles and Other Bottles 
        & Remove the bottle cap, empty the contents, rinse it with water and discharge it separately. Do not put foreign substances such as cigarette butts 
        * For beer bottles, etc., the empty container and deposit system is used at retail stores, etc. 
        \\  \cline{2-3}
\multirow{-4}{=}{Bottles}
    & Pesticide Bottles 
        & Rinse it with water and discharge it separately do not mix with beverage bottles. 
        \\  \hline
    & Scrap Metals (Tools, Steel Wires, Nails, Iron Plates, Electric Wires, etc.) 
        & Prevent mixing with foreign substances, place in a transparent bag or tie it with a string to dispose. 
        \\  \cline{2-3}
\multirow{-4}{=}{Metals}
    & Non-ferrous Metals (Nickel Silvers, Aluminums, Stainless Steels) 
        & Prevent mixing with foreign substances, place in a transparent bag or tie it with a string to dispose.
        \\  \hline
    & PET bottles, Synthetic resin containers.
        & Remove lid, empty contents, rinse with water and squeeze it to reduce the volume, as much as possible
        * Excluding waste oil containers. 
        \\  \cline{2-3}
    & Household goods 
        & Remove foreign substances, attached trademarks, etc. completely and place in a transparent vinyl or bundle them to dispose them.
        Empty the residue of fruits and fish boxes completely and rinse thoroughly with water to dispose. 
        \\  \cline{2-3}
\multirow{-9}{=}{Plastics}
    & Waste Styrofoam 
        & Excluding disposable cup noodle containers, lunch boxes and waste Styrofoam coated with foreign substances or other materials (PE, PP, etc.) \\
    \hline
Textiles 
    & Pure Wool, Mixed Wool, Innerwear, Outwear, etc. 
        & Except wet clothes, nylon, disposable diapers, quilted blankets, etc. Tie it using a string or dispose in a box or transparent vinyl. \\
    \hline
Batteries 
    & MR, SR 
        & Dispose in a transparent vinyl or box. 
        \\  \hline
Vinyl 
    & Snack Bags, Ramen Bags, Household Rubber Gloves, Disposable Plastic Bags, etc. 
        & Only plastic bags are collected separately and discharged. If foreign substances such as food are smeared, wash them thoroughly and dispose. 
        \\  \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Recyclables}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]